# Stopping URL rewrite if request is from specific subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is there a way to stop .htaccess from rewriting a URL if it is from a specific domain?

For example:

`example.com/test` usually rewrites to `example.com/pages/test.php`

`beta.example.com/test` will NOT rewrite. So goes to `beta.example.com/test` (same)

**Basically, what is the rule that looks for a subdomain and stops all rewrites after it?**

Comment: search the web for `RewriteCond`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the top of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This will make it so if the request is for `beta.example.com` it passes the URI through the entire rewrite engine without messing with it.

Comment: so the second line (`- [L]`) just says "stop rewriting"? I know `[L]` means last, what is the hyphen?

Comment: @NathanPetersen the `-` means to pass the URI through without doing anything to it. The `L` flag tells it to stop rewriting in the current iteration. This causes the rewrite engine to stop looping entirely because the URI is unchanged.